# Hook when category is added to post

Tags: categories, hooks

I'm trying to do something when a category is added to post and saved. I thought that using the `save_post` hook would have registered when a category is added to a post, but it doesn't appear to.

When I edit a post and do nothing but change the categories for the post, I don't get the `save_post` hook fired (editing the title, body, etc fires the `save_post` hook successfully). Is there another way to use `add_action`/`add_filter` to detect when a category is added to a post?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
do_action('set_object_terms', $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids);
```

You can find it under [this Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) and the action is located at [wp-includes/taxonomy.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php)

```
add_action('set_object_terms','wpse5123_set_object_terms',10,4);

function wpse5123_set_object_terms($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy){
       if($taxonomy == 'category'){
           echo '<pre>';
           print_r($terms);
           echo '</pre>';
           exit;
       }
}
```

The code above isn't tested but I think you get the point.